# Who is Croce Singing About in the "Hey, Tomorrow" Demo?

Tags: lyrics

In "Hey Tomorrow Demo" [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YYQqVfExQk), Croce sings at the end "I'll have a new day, if HE'LL have me" (in the "official" version, it's ""I'll have a new day, if SHE'LL have me").

Who was he singing about in the demo — God? Jesus?

As Croce was not homosexual, it's highly unlikely that he was referring to a male human. And since he converted to Judaism when he married his wife, it's probably not Jesus, either, so...